# ¿Cómo cargar un KML hosteado en google?

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome

En `visual Studio 2012` tengo el siguiente código:

```
    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            //url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/ssigkmldocs/serviciossigkml/2012-02-10.kml',
            //url: 'http://ssigprojdata.260mb.net/data/2012-02-10.kml',
            //url: 'data/kml/2012-02-10.kml',
            url: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/data/kml/2012-02-10.kml',
            format: new ol.format.KML()
        })
    });


    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: view
    });
```

Solo funciona la última url. Cuando quiero reemplazar esa línea por alguna otra url de arriba el Kml no se carga. ¿Alguien ha podido cargar su propio KML?

Solo quiero cargar un simple KML y aunque el ejercicio es sencillo no logro hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

No vas a poder.

Tanto la url que usas como la que te propone José generan un código de respuesta 302 que realiza una redirección a una nueva url.

Evidentemente es un sistema de Google para evitar descargas desde sitios web externos.

**EDITADO (21/05/2016)**

La dirección de google no te funciona porque no es una descarga directa, como ya te he comentado. Por la misma razón no funciona el link de ssigprojdata.260mb.net (aunque utiliza un sistema diferente para evitar estas descargas directas).

En cuanto al link al archivo alojado en tu sitio sólo hay dos posibles razones para que no te funcione: la ruta no es correcta o (más probablemente) tu servidor web está configurado para no permitir la descarga de este tipo de archivos.

Para probarlo trata de acceder desde tu navegador a la url del archivo directamente. Si recibes un error 404 deberías configurar tu servidor web para que sirva los archivos asignando un tipo MIME a la extensión kml.

Comment: Tiene todo el sentido... ¿Donde me recomendarías almacenar un kml para poder hacer lo que pretendo?

Comment: Si no existe un CDN desde el que puedas descargarlos creo que lo más lógico es que lo almacenes en la misma ubicación que las páginas que acceden a él.
De esta forma el correcto funcionamiento de tu aplicación depende únicamente de un servidor.

Comment: Lo coloco en la misma carpeta, de hecho inicialmente había intentado con "data/kml/2012-02-10.kml"  para apuntar al kml en mi proyecto... pero no funciona ni durante la programación ni al subirlo a mi host.

Comment: Si esta en la misma carpeta deberías poner como url únicamente el nombre del archivo "201202-10.kml"

Comment: ¿Alguien dispondrá de un ejemplo sencillo ya realizado? es solo que ni siquiera en mi maquina funciona localmente.

Comment: ¿Has probado a ponerlo en tu proyecto y acceder directamente desde el navegador? Como te comento en mi respuesta es muy posible que el problema no esté en tu código sino en la configuración del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

La dirección de google no lleva directamente al archivo KML en sí, si no a una página web para descargar el KML. Esto hace que no se carguen los features ya que ol.format.KML no puede parsear lo que recibe como KML y el método readFeatures() falla.

Prueba con la siguiente URL (Copiada del link que dice click aquí para descargar): 
https://sites.google.com/site/ssigkmldocs/serviciossigkml/2012-02-10.kml?attredirects=0

**EDITADO**

Imagina qué tienes este árbol de proyecto:

```
mi_proyecto
  - html
    - mapa.html
  - css
    - tus css
  - javascript 
    - tus javascripts
  - datos
    - kml
      - mikml.kml
```

entonces, suponiendo que el archivo donde cargas el kml es `mapa.html` deberías llamar al archivo `mikml.kml` de la siguiente forma :

```
url : '../datos/kml/mikml.kml'
```

Esto sería el path relativo al archivo kml desde la dirección actual.La notación `..` significa "ir para atrás", "ir a la carpeta anterior"

O bien puedes usar el path absoluto :

```
/datos/kml/mikml.kml
```

Si deseas alojar el archivo de forma remota, puedes crear un repositorio en github y alojarlo ahí, ya que permite acceder al archivo en su formato original `raw`.

Comment: Continuo en la misma problemática... he intentado guardando el KML en hosteadores ftp ... he intentado guardándolo en la carpeta raíz donde se encuentra mi pagina... google docs, drive y dropbox. Nada me funciona, estoy desesperada. Alguien tiene una idea?

Comment: Edita la pregunta e incluye por favor la estructura de tu proyecto donde cargas la página web y qué url pones en new ol.source.Vector({});

Comment: Edite la pregunta, y cree un raw en GitHub pero nada que funciona... Agradezco todas sus opiniones que me están dando. ¿hay alguna manera de ponerles aqui todo el proyecto en archivo ZIP o algo similar? para ver si alguien pudiera darle una checada a mi codigo, se me hace increíble que no puedo realizar un ejemplo tan básico.

Comment: Puedes subirlo a GitHub! Aunqur lo más sencillo es hacer un jsfiddle o un codepen del archivo que te da problemas.